# Basic Probability expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

Is $$E(\sum X^3)=\sum E(X^3)$$
I think that it shouldn't be true because $$\sum X^3$$ is just a number and how to find expectation of it?

Comment: Yes, it's true, because of linearity of the expectation

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: in addition to linearity of expectation in answer below, presumably $X$ is a random variable, in which case $\sum X^3$ is....? Less important: What are you summing over - is there more than one random variable involved, a set of $X_i$ for example?

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: It is not mentioned if the sum is a finite sum or an infinite sum.

Comment: We still cannot decide whether you mean the sum of different random variables, as the notation suggests and as the OP below opted for, or if you are interested in a single random variable, as all your comments seem to imply. (-1)

Comment: @V175 what I was trying to convey above is that in your post you say '$\sum X^3$ is just a number'. Whatever you are summing over, we have at least to assume $X$ is a random variable (or maybe shorthand for a set of random variables), therefore $\sum X^3$ isn't just a deterministic number, but am hoping you've inferred that from the various comments and answer..

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot. Until X is not a random variable, we can't say it's just a number ! Got it, now :) @Mehness

Comment: Hey, X is just a random variable. I'm sorry that I didn't mention if it's finite or not but will that make a difference and besides that, if it is infinite, how will you assign probabilities to them ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true, since expectation is linear. I.e., if $X,Y$ are random variables, and $\alpha, \beta$ are scalars, then $$E[\alpha X + \beta Y] = \alpha E[X] + \beta E[Y]$$

provided of course that both $X,Y$ have an expectation ("$X$ and $Y$ are integrable").

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Suppose, X takes value 0,1 and 2 with probability 1/3. Here, $$E(X^3)=3\Rightarrow \sum E(X^3)=3$$. But, how to find $$\sum E(X^3) ?$$ @Math_QED

Comment: What are you summing over? You can use the formula that $E[f(X)] = \sum f(x) P(X = x)$ where the sum runs over all values that $X$ attains, and where $f$ is the function $x \mapsto x^3$. So, for example $E[X^3] = 0^3P(X = 0) + 1^3P(X = 1) + 2^3P(X=2) = 1/3 + 8.1/3 = 9/3 = 3$.

Comment: Okay, Got it now! Thanks a lot :)  You explain it very nicely!

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to  consider to accept this answer.